# Chrome webdriver does not let me click a hamburger menu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the appearance of the html markup (A tile like object) I am testing with selenium.

[image]

The goal of the test is to trigger the drop down menu by clicking the hamburger icon as seen in the attached screenshot.

Here is the relevant code

```
    dropdown_menu = tile.find_element_by_class_name('dropdown-toggle')
    dropdown_menu.click()
```

When it comes to the `click` function call, I got this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (528, 125). Other element would receive the click: <span class="icon-file"></span>
```

The `icon-file` class is the blue icon on the top left corner of the tile.

However, when I test the same code in firefox I did not get this exception.

What is the likely cause of the difference of the behaviour?

Comment: There is a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2766) somewhat linked to this topic. It seems that an element must be clickable in it's center, which might not be the case for the hamburger menu. I recommend you read through the thread and check whether this applies in your case or not. Note. It does not seem to happen on Firefox, only Chrome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `time.sleep(5)` in between the two lines and it fixed the issue

```
dropdown_menu = tile.find_element_by_class_name('dropdown-toggle')
time.sleep(5)
dropdown_menu.click()
```

Thanks [Peanut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596532/peanut) for his link to the bug report in his comment